# tbm image search filter in image search query

Tags: html, filter

I am trying to mirror the google image search.
so far I know that q is the name for the actual google search (or query).
On the address it will look: [www.google.com/search?q=parrot](http://www.google.com/search?q=parrot)
but on the google image search also appears /search?q=parrot&tbm=ish

I looked and found out that tbm stands for "to be match" and is a filter and I guess is the filter to match the images... but I don't have a clue how to put inside my html code.

So far I have done this:

```
 <form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="form">
        <input type="text" name="q" class="search_bar"
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit">
    </form>
```

How do I add the tbm filter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden input field and set the value of it.

example

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="search_bar">
    <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="ish">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit">
</form>
```